# PyCharm 4 - Django Console gone

Tags: django, pycharm

Had both python and django console menu options in PyCharm in 3.4. Just switched to PyCharm 4 and the "Django Console" entry is gone. Do I have to activate it somewhere?

Trying to run django code within the python console leads to the usual error of settings module not having been configured. HEnce, the "automatic detection" does nit work.

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set correctly in /manage.py and main_module/uwsgi.py to point to "main_module.settings"

The project has been created with PyCharm 3.x. Maybe it does not detect the project for some reason as being a django project? Everything else seems to work fine: running django server, templates compeltion, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the solution by examining the settings of a newer project (created in a later version of PyCharm).

Put the following code in your Django Console settings (Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Django Console > Starting script):

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django; print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
import django_manage_shell; django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

This code is there by default when the project is made in a newer PyCharm.

Comment: This worked for me when also setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as noted in the comments below

Comment: I never had to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable. It was enough to set it in Settings  > Languages & Frameworks > Django > Settings.

Answer (score 6):

It was incapsulated in `Python console`. You can test you Django app in Python console.
From [JetBrains Blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/first-pycharm-4-preview-build-now-available/)

> Improved Python/Django console tool window
>
> PyCharm automatically detects which type of the console should be run
>   depending on your project type and context. The console can be
>   launched via the tools window menu as shown on the picture below or
>   using the “Ctrl+ E” shortcut:

Comment: How do I do that? If I import any module from my project I get the error: """ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."""

Or do I have to define the settings module each time I want to run django code?

Comment: @RomanSemko Check your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE env. variable. It should be configured with path to you priject setting.py

Comment: Not necessarily. In the question I state that "Trying to run django code within the python console leads to the usual error of settings module not having been configured." Hence, the automatic detection does not work.

Comment: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set correctly in wsgi.py and manage.py

Comment: PyCharm: Run->Edit Configuration->Environment Variables - check if DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set to youe settings.py

Comment: It was not set. But the run configuration (django server) was running just fine without it as well. Just added "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=main_module.settings" to the variables and restarted the console. Same error. ((

Comment: i have similar issue my django dev server is workign fine within pycharm 4 but python console is failing about issue with loading setting file :(